# In swift how to execute a command to ble device for retrieving a value from it. The commands returns value that will be in string

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, uart, bluetooth-gatt

The brush events shall be stored in a queue on the hardware device. Commands sent to the device are all human readable ASCII commands. All commands shall be carriage return (\r) terminated. If a command is not understood by the device, no response will come.
All responses to valid commands are in binary unless otherwise specified.

example: NUM_QUEUE
Description: This command reads the number of brush events still on the device Response: Single Byte containing number of events stored (up to 255)

Comment: Core Bluetooth is the framework you need, but aside from that your question needs a lot more detail for a succinct answer

Comment: It is said to use nordic uart service for data send and recieve. Can anyone help how to do that.

Comment: Unfortunately that is a bit like saying "my car is made by Toyota, can you tell me how to rebuild the engine?"